# Como corrigir o erro de APK completamente oculto?

Tags: android

Sempre que vou publicar um App na loja esse erro aparece:

> APK completamente oculto
>
> Problema: Este APK não será veiculado aos usuários, pois ele está
>   completamente oculto por um ou mais APKs com códigos de versão
>   superiores.
>
> Resolução: Remova este APK da versão ou revise os códigos de versão e a
>   segmentação dos APKs incluídos nela.

Comment: Qual é a **versionCode** e **versionName** está na loja e qual está tentando subir?

Comment: Acredito que são os mesmos. Eu estou tentando subir uma nova versão pela quinta vez e da primeira e segunda deu certo, da terceira até a quinta aparece essa mensagem. Como deveriam estar os nomes?

Comment: Então, o **version code** deve o incrementar mais um! Se é **10** por exemplo, a versão que está no Google Play, a próxima a subir deve ser a **11**

Comment: Então.. a versão atual publicada na loja é a 2, já tentei publicar a versão 3 e 4 e aparece o erro de que "Você já tem um APK com o código de versão 3 ou 4" E quando tento enviar uma que ainda não tentei ele apresenta esse erro do tópico.

Comment: TENTEI AGORA COLOCAR A VERSÃO 6 E DEU CERTO! MUITO OBRIGADO!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como apontado pelo [Thiago Luiz Domacoski](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/25969/thiago-luiz-domacoski), para publicar um novo APK na Google Play, o valor do **versionCode** no seu gradle, deve ser maior que o valor do último APK que está publicado.

```
 defaultConfig {

    /* ... */

    versionCode 2 // <---- Número da versão do app
    versionName "nome da versao"

    /* ... */
}
```

Para saber qual o valor do versionCode da última versão publicada de um app:

1. Abra o Google Play Developer Console
2. Selecione um app
3. Selecione **Gerenciamento da Versão** no menu lateral
4. Clique em **Versões de Apps** no submenu
5. Nas informações que aparecem procure por *código da versão do APK*. Esse é o seu ultimo versionCode utilizado, portanto, a próxima versão que você for publicar para esse app, deve ter um número maior que esse.

Comment: Então.. a versão atual é a 2, estou tentando enviar a versão 3 e diz que " O envio falhou

Use outro código de versão para seu APK. Você já tem um APK com o código de versão 3." . Isso deve acontecer por que eu já tentei enviar outra vez. Como havia dado erro com a versão 3 eu desisti e fui para a próxima e o erro persistiu com a versão 4 e agora com a 5.

Comment: Você poderia editar a pergunta adicionando o print da tela de publicação?

Comment: TENTEI AGORA COLOCAR A VERSÃO 6 E DEU CERTO! MUITO OBRIGADO!!!

Comment: Outro ponto também é que por algum motivo o Play Console pode não ter colocado a versão anterior para ser desativada, e aí essa mensagem aparece. Quando coloquei "Desativar" a versão anterior, o erro sumiu também

Answer (score 0):

no meu caso eu tenho mudado/alterar esse versionCode, mas segue dando o mesmo aviso.
Então, agora apaguei as apks que já subi para ver se esse alerta some.

Comment: Pessoal, consegui, é isso mesmo! Tem que ser apagadas/removidas as apks anteriores pra poder subir uma nova.