# Atualizar APK Google Play - APK não atualizável

Tags: android, google-play, apk

Estou tentando atualizar um App e não estou conseguindo. É mostrado a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Nenhum dos usuários que têm este APK instalado conseguirá fazer
>   upgrade para um dos APKs adicionados nesta versão.

[image: Imagem]

Comment: Alterou a versão no `gradle`? Adicionou alguma limitação que seus usuários — ainda — não possuem?

Comment: @ValdeirPsr alterei a versão do gradle sim. Não pode alterar ?

Comment: Pode alterar sim, mas antes de subir é necessário alterar o `versionCode` e `versionName` **no** gradle.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr sim eu fiz isso. :/

Comment: Por um acaso mudou a assinatura ou a chave do aplicativo usada para assinar o apk?

Comment: @GrupoCDSInformática não, já atualizei outras vezes e somente agora deu esse problema. Vou refazer todo o processo para ver se consigo.

Comment: Veja se isto resolve https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/235268/3635