# APK não atualizavel

Tags: android, ionic, apk

estou tentando atualizar um app na loja google play
incrementei o version code, gerei o apk com a mesma chave, no entanto,
a loja apresenta o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

alguma dica de como resolver esse problema?
estou usando ionic/cordova
android@7.0.0

ps: talvez eu tenha atualizado o gradle

Comment: Muito dificil saber o que houve com só isto de informação :/

Comment: mas quais outras coisas poderiam ser? tipo quais sao os principais erros que causam essa rejeição?

Comment: Posta o que fez, o que modificou. Você reinstalou algo, fica muito amplo de responder assim e se é algo muito amplo então a pergunta esta fora do escopo aceito do site, entende? Tente dar detalhes.

Comment: estou praticamente com o mesmo erro que https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/267005/atualizar-apk-google-play-apk-n%C3%A3o-atualiz%C3%A1vel

Comment: E lá percebe que também não obteve respostas né? Isto ocorre por falta de detalhes, o problema dele final pode ser igual ao seu, mas a origem do problema pode ser totalmente diferente, só que ambas e diferentes falhas causaram um mesmo problema.

Comment: Veja se isto resolve https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/235268/3635

Comment: ja alterei, simplesmente aparece essa mensagem. Talvez seja arquitetura? porque a dica diz para eu me certificar que todos os apks sejam adicionados a versão, o que isso significa? nao consigo saber o erro simplesmente com essa mensagem .

Comment: Você ajustou a versão do teu APK? O versionamento serve para isto, tipo 1.0.1, 1.0.2, etc. No gradle se estiver algo como `versionName "1.1"` altere para `versionName "1.2"` ou maior, deve ser isso.

Comment: alterei a versão e no terminal rodei **ionic cordova build android --prod** aparentemente não estava alternado a versão sem da o build.... agradeço a dica. problema resolvido

Comment: aumente "versionCode" de seu app... vai funcionar!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Atualizar seus apps**

**Preparar seu APK**

> Quando você estiver pronto para fazer modificações no seu APK,
>   atualize também o código de versão do app para que os usuários recebam
>   essa atualização.
>
> Use a seguinte lista de verificação para conferir se o novo APK está
>   pronto para atualizar os usuários existentes:
>
> - O nome de pacote do APK atualizado precisa ser o mesmo da versão
>     atual.
> - O código da versão precisa ser superior ao da versão atual.
>     Saiba mais sobre o [controle de versão de seus apps](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html).
> - O APK atualizado precisa ser marcado com a mesma assinatura da versão atual.
>
> Para verificar se o seu APK está usando a mesma certificação da versão
>   anterior, é possível executar o seguinte comando em ambos os APKs e
>   comparar os resultados:
>
> ```
> $ jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs my_application.apk
> ```
>
> Se os resultados forem idênticos, isso significa que você usa a mesma
>   chave e está pronto para continuar. Se os resultados forem diferentes,
>   será necessário assinar o APK novamente com a chave correta.
>
> - Saiba mais sobre como [assinar seus apps](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html).

**Fazer upload do seu APK**

> Depois que seu APK estiver pronto, será possível [criar uma nova versão](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7159011).

**Entrega de atualizações**

> Depois de enviar uma atualização para um app, você verá "Atualização pendente" no canto superior direito das páginas do Play Console do app. Assim que a atualização for publicada, ela começará a ser distribuída para os usuários existentes.
>
> Quando a atualização estiver disponível, os usuários poderão fazer
>   download dela na página "Detalhes do app" ou na página **Meus apps** do
>   app Play Store. Se um usuário tiver ativado as atualizações automáticas do seu app, a atualização será transferida e instalada automaticamente.
>
> As atualizações do app levam algum tempo para chegar aos usuários
>   existentes. Caso você tenha enviado uma atualização que ainda não
>   tenha aparecido no Google Play, espere pelo menos 24 horas antes de
>   entrar em contato com nossa equipe de suporte.

**Atualizar apps do sistema**

> Os usuários verão os apps do sistema (incluindo apps pré-carregados)
>   na seção Meus apps da Google Play Store assim que um app com o mesmo
>   nome de pacote for enviado para o Play Console (mesmo se o app não
>   tiver sido publicado).
>
> O Google Play pode gerenciar atualizações de apps pré-carregados, uma
>   vez que as seguintes condições sejam atendidas:
>
> - O aplicativo pré-carregado precisa estar na partição do sistema
> - O aplicativo pré-carregado precisa ser gratuito
> - O app pré-carregado precisa ter a mesma assinatura do app publicado no Google Play
> - O nome de pacote do app pré-carregado e do app atualizado precisa ser o mesmo
> - O código de versão do app atualizado precisa ser superior ao do pré-carregado